# No puedo concatenar una variable con una consulta sql, la variable almacena el valor de un formulario. No me devuelve la tabla

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos, mysqli, variables

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que trato de hacer es que a través de un formulario ingresen la tabla a buscar e imprimirla a continuación con todos sus campos

Comment: Jose Nuñes creo que el error esta en el $query.. ¿Porque le pones un punto y comilla simple?

Comment: soy nuevo en esto de php y he intentado varias formas para concatenar la variable con la consulta pero no tengo resultados :c

Comment: Si le quitas el punto y las comillas simples obtendrás el valor. Te lo pongo en una respuesta.

Comment: Está bien men, probaré con lo que dices.

Comment: Si funcionó men, yara no probé eso, muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: No olvides darle click en "calificar la respuesta" si es que te funciona. Saludos

Comment: listo, pero sale que mis votos no cambian la puntuación :v

Comment: Debe ser en la "paloma", en el "bien", no se como lo identifiques. Pero lo más importante es que solucionaste tu problema. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que pruebes primero la conexión a la base de datos, supliendo la variable `$busqueda` por el nombre de tu tabla. Ahí te veras que el error esta en el `$query`. Ya que solo debe ser:

```
 SELECT * FROM tabla 
 SELECT * FROM $busqueda
```